# (webpack) What is the difference between "output.publicPath" and "devServer.publicPath"?

Tags: webpack

Doc is quite clear about [output.publicPath](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath), and I understand how to use it. But what should I do with `devServer.publicPath` option? Should I use it at all, if doc says, that dev-server also uses `output.publicPath`?

For example, running webpack-dev-server with config like this:

```
{
  output: {
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: "/static/",
  },

  devServer: {
    publicPath: "/",
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
}
```

I see that is says in terminal "webpack result is served from /", but in generated html file link still points to "/static/app.js" – and, the most strange thing – that bundle is not found. It works only if these options have same value, or only one of these options is used.

How to use all this stuff properly?

I'm using webpack 1.13.2 and webpack-dev-server 1.16.1.